# Converting apache rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I want to convert a few apache rules to nginx.

### Apache rules

```
deny from 127.1.1.4    
deny from 127.1.1.1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$                       /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
RewriteRule    ([0-9A-Za-z]{12})-del-([0-9A-Za-z]+)/.+$     /cgi-bin/index.cgi?del=$1-$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]*)/?([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(/[^\/]*|)(\.html?|$)$  /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&usr_login=$1&id=$2&fname=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)(/[0-9a-z\-_]*/?|$)$       /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=user_public&usr_login=$1&fld=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule    ^latest-files(\d*).html$             /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=catalogue&page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+).html(.*)            /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=$1$2 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

### And nginx rules

```
rewrite ^/free([0-9]+)\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=registration&aff_id=$1 last;
rewrite  ^/(checkfiles|contact|login|links)\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=$1 last;
rewrite ^/premium\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=payments last;
rewrite ^/catalogue(.*)\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=catalogue&date=$1 last;
rewrite ^/news([0-9]*)\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=news&page=$1 last;
rewrite ^/n([0-9]+)-.*\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=news_details&news_id=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(faq|tos)\.html$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=$1 last;
rewrite "^/(?!tmp/)([0-9A-Za-z]{12})(\/.+|\.html?|$)" /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=download1&id=$1&fname=$2 last;
rewrite "^/users/([0-9A-Za-z\-_]{4,64})/?([0-9]+|$)" /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=user_public&usr_login=$1&fld_id=$2 last;
rewrite ^/pages/([a-z0-9\-\_]+).html /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=page&tmpl=$1 last;

location / {
     root   /etc/nginx/html;
     index  index.html index.htm;
     rewrite ^  /cgi-bin/index.cgi last;
}
```

There is something wrong with nginx rules (for example: images/* and css files 'link' to index.cgi)

Any idea about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
location = / { root /etc/nginx/html; index index.html index.htm; rewrite ^ /cgi-bin/index.cgi last; }
```

`location /` means anything that begins with `/`

`location = /` means just `/`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following site that might help you to get it done:

http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: Link only answers are considered bad practice. If that article or site goes down this answer becomes worthless. I'd recommend a brief summary at least.